If a sum $\sum_{k<x} a_k$ is asymptotically less than $\sum_{k<x} b_k$ , then $\sum_{k<x} (a_k)^n < \sum_{k<x} (b_k)^n $ if the second sum converges.
If $\sum_{k<x} a_k $ is asymptotically less than $\sum_{k<x} b_k$, can we say that:
If for some $n$ $\sum_{k<x} (b_k)^n $ converges, then $\sum_{k<x} (a_k)^n <  \sum_{k<x} (b_k)^n $?
What I mean by asymptotically less is for example: $\sum_{k<x} a_k  = \log(\log(x)) + c + o(1)$ and $\sum_{k<x} b_k = \log(x) + d + o(1) $.  In this case the sum of the second powers of $b_k$ will converge, by a suitable comparison with $1/n$, since the sum of $1/n$ has similar assymptotics and the sum of $1/n^2$ converges. A similar argument assures us that the sum of the $a_k$'s converges, but I cannot show that it must converge to less than $b_k$.
Here you can assume that the terms are always positive.

In general, $\sum_{k\geq 1} (a_k)^n < \sum_{k\geq 1} (b_k)^n$ will not hold. For example, let $b_k = 1/k$ and define
$$ a_1 = 10, \quad \quad a_k = \frac{1}{k\log k} \quad k \geq 2,$$
then we have that the partial sums $\sum_{k\leq x} b_k \sim \log x$ are asymptotically larger than $\sum_{k \leq x} a_k \sim \log \log x$. Nevertheless
$$\sum_{k \geq 1} b_k^2 = \pi^2/6 < 100 < \sum_{k \geq 1} a_k^2 <\infty.$$
Edit: Upon further thought, we can see that the convergence of $\sum_{k\geq 1} b_k^n$ does not imply convergence of $\sum_{k \geq 1} a_k^n$.
For example, take $b_k = 1/k$ and
$$
a_k = \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} & k = 2^m \,\text{for}\, m \in \mathbb{N}\\
 \frac{1}{k\log k} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2^m+1}^{2^{m+1}} b_k &= \sum_{k=2^m+1}^{2^{m+1}} \frac{1}{k}\\
&\geq \frac{2^m}{2^{m+1}} = \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{align}
On the other hand
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2^m+1}^{2^{m+1}} a_k &= \sum_{k=2^m+1}^{2^{m+1}-1} \frac{1}{k\log k} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \\
&\leq \frac{2^{m}}{(2^m+1)\log (2^m+1)} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \\
&\leq \frac{2^{m}}{m2^m\log 2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} \\
&= \frac{1}{m\log 2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}
\end{align}
These calculations show that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^N b_k} = 0 
\end{equation}
However, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k^2 = \pi^2/6$, meanwhile the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2$ diverges since $(a_k^2)_{k \geq 1}$ contains the subsequence $(1/m)_{m\geq 1}$ whose sum diverges.
Edit 2 The above example also works if we take
\begin{align}
a_k = \begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} & k = 2^m \,\text{for}\, m \in \mathbb{N}\\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which simplifies the computation a bit. It is also easier to see how the limit of sums behaves because now $\sum_{k=1}^N a_k \sim \sqrt{\log N}$.

Then may I make a similar question? Can we have that the sum of (b_k)^n converges and that the sum (a_k)^n doesnt?

@RicardoMM Yes, it's possible. Check the updated answer.

Nice construction! I think I need to rethink some proof atempts I made before, now.
